# Loop UP through all parent nodes of a node in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm trying to change the icon of a node down in a JTree then change all of the Nodes it took to get there. Here is what I have so far.

```
   private void LoopDirectoryTree(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, File lua_file, String icon_url) {

        int childCount = node.getChildCount();

        TreeIcon t_node = (TreeIcon)node.getUserObject();

        if(t_node.getFile().equals(lua_file)){
            t_node.setIcon(icon_url);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {

            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getChildAt(i);
            if (childNode.getChildCount() > 0) {

                LoopDirectoryTree(childNode, lua_file, icon_url);

            } else {

                t_node = (TreeIcon)childNode.getUserObject();

                // THIS IS WHERE I TRIED TO GO BACK UP (refer below)
                if(t_node.getFile().equals(lua_file)){

                    // Icon to change
                    t_node.setIcon(icon_url);

                }

            }

        }
   }
```

I tried something along the lines of:

```
   if(t_node.getFile().equals(lua_file)){

      // Icon to change
      t_node.setIcon(icon_url);

      while(childNode.getParent()!=null){

          childNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)childNode.getParent();
          t_node = (TreeIcon)childNode.getUserObject();

          // Icon to change (DIFFERENT ICON THAN OTHER)
          t_node.setIcon(NEW_ICON_URL);

      }

   }
```

But that did not work as expected.

Basically, I have a JTree of folder and files. I parse a file to check for syntax and if it is bad I want to show that file with a BAD parsed file icon and all it's parent folders in the JTree, I want to be a BAD parsed folder icon.

Answer (score 0):

i think your best bet would be to use getPathToRoot() to traverse the JTree.

**Example solution**

```
 if(t_node.getFile().equals(lua_file)){

  // Icon to change
  t_node.setIcon(icon_url);
  TreeNode[] pathToRoot = ((DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel()).getPathToRoot(node);
  for(TreeNode nToChangeIcon: pathToRoot){
    ((TreeNode)nToChangeIcon.getUserObject()).setIcon(NEW_ICON_URL);     
  }
```

}

When you use getPathToRoot(node), it returns an array of TreeNodes. The first index of the TreeNodes[] is the root of your tree model. The next node in TreeNodes[] is the child of the root that leads to 'node', and so on, until 'node' is reached.

So by using the for loop to go through each node in TreeNodes[] pathToRoot, you will have the correct path to node, without having to use getChildAt().

From my understanding, you want to change the Icon of each node in the path to 'node' as long as your if condition is met. So using the enhanced for loop to go through each TreeNode in pathToRoot[] will allow you to change the icon of each node (including the node that t_node came from)